# How to add api key value with a function, may be syntax error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, function

Trying to generalize some activities by creating a common function and it's parameters.

```js
function changevalue(source_id, target_id, array_key) {
  var selectedValue = $(source_id).getSelectedItemData().array_key;
  $(target_id).val(selectedValue).trigger("change");
}

changevalue(title_id, firstname_id, email_key);
```

- source_id & target_id : Textbox IDs
- email_key : keyvalue from an API (https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users)

When i'm trying to run this function getting 'Cannot read property 'getSelectedItemData' of undefined'

getting an error in **getSelectedItemData().email_key ;** area.

Seems like a synatx error in the clubbing of email_key with function is causing issue.

Comment: How you are getting `email-key` here?

Comment: @HarshJaswal :  from an api - https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users

Comment: @CertainPerformance : am passing # while calling the function

Comment: you need to give the index of the `email_key`, like `jsonName[0].email`

Comment: @HarshJaswal: if am removing the function and hard coreded the values its works well.

Comment: var person_firstname = $(source_id).getSelectedItemData().email;
                $(target_id).val(person_firstname).trigger("change");

Comment: If  `source_id` is the element id and `array_key` is a dynamic key, you should probably change the first line to be `var selectedValue = $('#'+source_id).getSelectedItemData()[array_key];`